# How do I make summoned falling_blocks look like a block other than sand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a 2x3 area that I want to be Magenta Carpet on Minecraft Realms (1.15.2/vanilla) Java 1.8.0_51.  My goal is to have a fake floor that somebody falls through.

```
/summon minecraft:falling_block -261 39 -2426 {Block:"minecraft:magenta_carpet", NoGravity:1}
/summon minecraft:falling_block -261 39 -2427 {Block:"minecraft:magenta_carpet", NoGravity:1}
/summon minecraft:falling_block -261 39 -2428 {Block:"minecraft:magenta_carpet", NoGravity:1}
/summon minecraft:falling_block -260 39 -2426 {Block:"minecraft:magenta_carpet", NoGravity:1}
/summon minecraft:falling_block -260 39 -2427 {Block:"minecraft:magenta_carpet", NoGravity:1}
/summon minecraft:falling_block -260 39 -2428 {Block:"minecraft:magenta_carpet", NoGravity:1}
```

I have also tried:

- without `minecraft:`
- with `TileID`/`Data` instead of `Block`
- with `Block:carpet, Data:2`
- with quotes around the property name as per JSON specs like `"Block":"..."`

However, all of the blocks look like sand, not magenta carpet. How do I make them look like carpet instead?

Comment: Please note that b should be added to the NoGravity NBT tag, to specify its data type as Boolean. The interpreter should get it anyway, but it's better grammar to clarify. E.g. {NoGravity:1b}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your command is just a bit malformed, from some tutorials and testing I have found you can do it as follows:

```
/summon minecraft:falling_block -261 39 -2426 {BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:magenta_carpet"}, NoGravity:1b, Time:1, DropItem:0b}
```

What is important to also note is that you also need the Time data, which states how many ticks the entity has. According to this [Minecraft Wiki guide](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Falling_blocks) (as of this post's creation) it states than a value of 0 is a despawn, a value of 1 to 599 means the entity stays spawned, and a value of 600 is also a despawn. This means the entity can live at most 30 seconds before despawning, according to the guide.

What is also important to note is the DropItem:0b since this means you won't drop a carpet at the end of the 30 seconds.

If you use this method to generate a fake floor, you will need to use repeating command blocks or a clock attached to one to respawn it every 600 ticks.